# Threejs youtube iframe disables FirstPersonControls after being clicked

Tags: youtube, three.js

I have a youtube video that I am loading in createScene(). The video loads and plays, but it disables my FirstPersonControls. I tried to attach click events to both the element and the iframe, but I'm not having any luck in catching the event. My theory is that I could use e.preventDefault(), but I'm not sure if that would even work. I am using CSS3DRenderer to render the CSS3D object.

In [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_youtube.html) you are able to start the youtube vid and still use the threejs controls. For me, after I click on the youtube widget, none of my keyboard keys work anymore, and the only thing I can interact with is the youtube widget, no other objects in my scene.

Not really sure what to show in my code that could be causing the issue...

```
var YoutubePlane = function (id, x, y, z, ry) {
    let element = document.createElement('div')
    let width = '500px'
    let height = '400px'

    element.style.width = width;
    element.style.height = height;
    element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
    element.className = 'three-div'

    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    // iframe.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    iframe.style.width = width
    iframe.style.height = height
    iframe.style.border = '0px'
    iframe.src = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/', id, '?rel=0&controls=0'].join('')
    element.appendChild(iframe)

    let div = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element)
    div.position.set(x, y, z)
    div.rotation.y = ry
    div.name = "youtube"

    return div;
}
```

One thing to note: While the keyboard controls are disabled, the click control still works (moves camera forward).

Comment: Since this is a controls issue, it seems odd to supply the code that adds an object to the scene. From your description, that's working fine. Mouse events in any JavaScript application can be tricky when child frames are involved. Do you have a jsfiddle or codepen you can share? Adding events to Document should not be getting superseded by Window and Frame focus. Do your controls target an Element or Window rather than Document? Three.js defaults to Document on most controls classes, but you mention "my firstPersonControls" so there's not enough info here.

Comment: To repeat @Radio's excellent point: if you want help with such a specific issue and are not able to pinpoint the problematic code yourself, you'll need to provide an online example we can take a look at.

Comment: @Radio I tried to make a codepen, but It's not loading the CSS3DRenderer. I am loading 2 scenes with 2 renderer because I am using the CSS3D stuff.  But I'm having no luck loading it on codepen. Code just errors out (but I cant see the error because its on the backend I guess).  Guess I need to make another Stack Overflow post just for that! Jkjk

But I haven't done anything as far as events to the Iframe. It clicks and plays at it does by default. But I'm never able to regain control of my FirstPersonControls.